# Why is $\sum_{d\mid p^r}\phi(d)=\sum_{h=0}^r\phi(p^h)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$\sum_{d\mid p^r}\phi(d)=\sum_{h=0}^r\phi(p^h)$

I read this relation in a proof, but can't work out why it is the case.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $p$ is a prime number (which is reasonable and necessary for this to be true), the set of divisors of $p^r$ is $1, p, p^2, \dots, p^r$. So summing over all $d \mid p^r$ and summing over $p^i$ from $i=0$ to $r$ is the exact same thing.

(The $\phi$ is tangential for this, it would be true for any function whatsoever.)

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious since $\{ \mbox{divisors of } p^r\} = \{ 1, p, \dots, p^r \}$, so roughly speaking you have
$$\sum_{d|p^r} f(d)= \sum_{j=0}^rf(p^j) = f(1) + f(p) + \cdots + f(p^r)$$
whenever $f$ is any function.